# How to count rows with rounded valus in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, count, teradata

I work in SQL Teradata.

I would liek to count how many rows (clients) have rounded value in column "amount" (means for example 140.00 not 157.76 and so on). I use code like below:

```
    select 
    client_id, 
    count(amount mod 1 = 0)
    from table
    group by client_id
```

Nevertheless, I have an error like: `SELECT Failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between an integer and '='.`

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
sum(case when amount mod 1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
```

I'm not 100% sure if Teradata supports `mod 1`.  I would normally write this as:

```
sum(case when amount = floor(amount) then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: Hmm I used both of your solutions and I have different results for clients, which one is better for my case? to calculate how many rounded values has each client ?

Comment: @gato . . . You should look at the data to see which does exactly what you want.  I'm not sure why these would return different results.

Comment: Teradata supports mod, including mod 1.  It will return a decimal value if the input is a decimal - `cast (10 as decimal(5,2)) mod 1` will return 0.00.  But 0.00 does = 0.